# Any shortcut key to find out the class name of a specific funtion in VS Code

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

In VS code, is there any quick way to find out which class my currently selected function is in? Imagine the class is huge, and keep scrolling up is painful. I'm using Python.

Comment: what language are you using? that makes a difference. this doc may give you want you are looking for: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved  you request sounds like `Go to Definition`, `Go to Type Definition`, or `Go to Implementation`

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Python. I have read that page before, none of the tricks apply to my question